# How to Slide Down One Keyboard Slide Up a Custom One

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I have four textFields in a view.
The first three are edited with a standard Keyboard.
The last is edited with a picker that as the inputView property of the textField.
This is cool because it handles the slide up and down.

Imagine I am typing something in one of the first three textFields with a standard keyboard.
Now I tap on the fourth row.
I want the standard keyboard to retract and the picker to slide up.
Right now it just swaps instantly.

I've tried using the textField delegate methods to write logic to resignFirstResponder on the standard keyboard and becomeFirst responder with the picker but it still changes instantly. Here's the code.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
//If we go from a keyboard field to a picker field
if ((self.textFieldBeingEdited == self.nameField || self.locationField || self.controllerSNField)){
    if (textField == equipTypeField) {

        //Put away the keyboard
        [self.textFieldBeingEdited resignFirstResponder];

        //Show the Picker
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}   
}
```

I also need to write logic to slide the picker down and slide up the keyboard if I go from the fourth view to any of the others. But if I can get the first half the second should be obvious.

Any idea how to do this without getting into animation blocks? Maybe with Notifications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that you already have begun editing by the time that method is called, so the call to `resignFirstResponder` does nothing, because it isn't the first responder any more.  Perhaps if you make it become the first responder again, it might work.  But then calling `becomeFirstResponder` on the `equipTypeField` may cause `textFieldDidBeginEditing` to get called again, getting you stuck in an infinite loop.  A quandry, no doubt.  But in the very least, I would try this:

```
//So that the keyboard that animates out is the one that was previously showing
[self.textFieldBeingEdited becomeFirstResponder];
//Animate the keyboard out
[self.textFieldBeingEdited resignFirstResponder];
//Don't let the user screw anything up
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
//Animate the new keyboard in a little while later
[textField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
//Let the user interact with the application again after the animation completes
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(endIgnoringInteractionEvents) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
```

This still leaves open the question of where to put this code, since if you put it in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, you might get an infinite loop.  My suggestion would be to try it and see what happens.  If it works, great, otherwise, put in some sort of boolean flag or something to make sure you only call it once before didFinishEditing is called.

Comment: It didn't work but I did learn a thing or two from your solution. I see what you mean about the infinite loop. Thanks.